# Salesforce autentication with active directory

Tags: identity, activedirectory

I'm tring to understand how salesforce is working with active directory (using identity connect).
With identity connect i can sync the information from AD to salesforce and choosing my mapping method.
But what is the flow of the autentication process? who is taken part in this process (salesforce, AD, identity connect)?

anouther question: how can i make the connection between a user in salesforce to the original user in AD? there is some api that give me the SID?

thanks,
Kobi

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Single_Sign-On_with_Force.com_and_Microsoft_Active_Directory_Federation_Services

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual login process is as follows:

- User goes to a My Domain (something.my.salesforce.com).
- My Domain sends the user to Identity Connect via SAML.
- Identity Connect verifies the user's identity against Active Directory.
- Identity Connect sends the user to the Salesforce login with a SAML assertion.
- Salesforce validates the SAML assertion and gives the user a Session Id.

The components involved are the user's web browser, Identity Connect, Salesforce.com, and Active Directory.

Identity Connect, like other forms of Single-Sign On, map the user based on a "Federated ID". This is normally their Active Directory user name, though you could choose to use a different attribute if you really wanted to. You can also sync additional custom attributes on the mapping screen in Identity Connect.